# Draw Alternate vertices in OpenGL VBO

Tags: opengl, vbo

I am learning how to manipulate and draw vbo objects between OpenCL and OpenGL.
I have an array of float4 vertices in a VBO to describe lines which I am rendering using:

```
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, rbo);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof( float4 ), 0);

glColor4f(1, 0, 1, 0.4);
glPointSize(1);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, db_rays);
```

etc...

But I would like to only render each other (i.e. alternate) vertices in the array as points (so GL_POINTS). Is there a smart way to tell openGL to do this?

I have tried

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof( float4 )*2, 0);
```

But this doesn't seem to draw anything?
S

Comment: Did you also change the `count` attribute you pass to `glDrawArrays`  accordingly. Beside that you should use `glGetError` or `GL_ARB_debug_output` if an error and what kind of error occurs.

Comment: *facepalm* looks like I should have had a second coffee - yes this solves it!